# GCP - Compute Instance running active directory DNS config and sometimes failure on client startup

Tags: active-directory, google-compute-engine

I maintain an infrastructure with 2 Domain Controllers (DC) and other servers for Remote Desktop Services (RDS) infrastructure.
The 2 DC run also DNS server for local AD domain, so on the other servers I will use the DC IP as DNS Server Address.
In the RDS infrastructure there are some Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH) that overnight are turned off.
Sometimes a random server fail at startup, in the event viewer I can't find specific error, but all event show a network error, more specifically a DNS error, for example:

> Log Name:      System
>   Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Time-Service
>   Date:          19/02/2019 08:20:52
>   Event ID:      134
>   Task Category: None
>   Level:         Warning
>   Keywords:
>   User:          LOCAL SERVICE
>   Description:
>   NtpClient was unable to set a manual peer to use as a time source because of DNS resolution error on '”metadata.google.internal,0x1'”'. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval thereafter. The error was: No such host is known. (0x80072AF9)

Or in the application event

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        GCEMetadataScripts
>   Date:          19/02/2019 08:20:51
>   Event ID:      2
>   Task Category: None
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Description:
>   ERROR: 2019/02/19 08:20:51.435448 main.go:258: GCEMetadataScripts: ERROR main.go:258: error connecting to metadata server, retrying in 3s, error: Get http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/?recursive=true&alt=json&timeout_sec=10&last_etag=NONE: dial tcp: lookup metadata.google.internal: getaddrinfow: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

So I think that mi machine can't resolve internal google domains using MS DNS.

Is there a way to manually configure google internal DNS in the instance? What are IP addresses of Google Internal DNS?

Thank you all.

Davide.

Comment: Can the VMs or other external sites VMs be pinged during the startup failures? There could be other root causes. I’m not certain if the issue you’re encountering is due to strictly due to DNS resolution since you mentioned that the failure occurs only intermittently.
Information on Internal DNS address for the VMs metadata Server is listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#access_by_internal_DNS)
“By default, resolution of internal DNS names is handled by the instance's metadata server (169.254.169.254)”

Comment: I don't know if during failure VMs ping something, they are Windows instance and i couldn't access them. But I know that the VMs couldn't be pinged during failure. I don't think that is a resolution problem, but I have the doubt that setting the dns manually with AD dns cause some problem on the network. There are other error that make think network error, for example the VMs couldn't reach NTP server.